# Insomnia: Invalid JSON: Unexpected token ) in JSON at position 0

Tags: json, rest, xpath, jsonpath, insomnia

This is response of the Login request that i need to extract data from.
As you can see first line is not JSON format and Insomnia is complaining about it as **"Invalid JSON: Unexpected token ) in JSON at position 0"**

Is there any way to ignore/remove first line then extract data? May be custom query?

```
)]}',
{
    "userid": "USER1",    
    "email": "user1@email.com",    
    "name": "John Jones"
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one-off, just delete the first line with a text editor.

If it's happening systematically, then (a) you really ought to get it fixed at source rather than repairing it after the event, and (b) you need to know what the general pattern of bad data is, rather than working from one example.

Comment: I'm trying to get data from one request to another, extracted data will be used in multiple places.

Comment: this is not one output, all responses has extra line at the beginning and i have no control on changing the source.